# kitchen cabinet plumbing

Tags: kitchen-sink

I am replacing my kitchen cabinets. I am not sure how to handle the 2in PCV drain from the sink- ie should I cut the PVC, make a hole in the cabinet and join the pipe or cut a "U" slot in the cabinet and slide it down (ie avoid cuts to the drain pipe). How is it normally done and if I have to cut the PVC and re-join- is it easy ? Appreciate any suggestions / links to related videos.
I have attached an image of the drain pipe.

[image]

Comment: The disposal wiring looks like a code violation, assuming you live somewhere with normal electrical codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most usual approach given what you have would be to cut the pipe and install a union, so the pipe can be taken apart and put back together. Obviously the last person chose "cut a big weird hole" as well as doing some very dodgy wiring while they were at it.

You'll need to do the same for the supply pipes.

Comment: Hardwiring a disposal isn't OK?

Comment: @Huesmann Using NM/B as cordage isn't OK. Using NM/B exposed to damage isn't OK. Zip-tying it to the drain pipe violates "in a neat and professional manner" not to mention common sense. If you want to hardwire the disposal, you need to switch to AC/MC/MC-Lite armored cable where it pops out of the wall, AIUI. I have to wonder if there's a blind junction box concealed behind the cabinet, though I suppose for this level of hackery the cable just magically sprouts from the drywall with no box at all - either of which is not OK.

Answer (score 1):

It would be normal to have screw or pressure fittings for these bends so that you can remove a section to clear out blockages.

If thats not the case, then go ahead and cut it.  It is easy enough to fix as long as you are away from the edge of the elbow.  Either cut out the whole elbow or leave some pipe at the end of it.

Comment: Thank you  for the pressure fittings idea.